# compareing multiple words in python and having multiple icons

Tags: python

```
words = "i" "am" "a" "programmer"
    list = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
    vowels2 = 0 
    cconsonants = 0
    for l in words:
        if l in list:
            vowels2 +=1
        else:
            cconsonants +=1
    print("The word i contains more vowels than consonants.")
    print("The word a contains more vowels than consonants.")
```

this is an overview to a multi part program i need to wr
so this is what i have so far and my question is how can i make it so that the bottom is able to read each word and print them out in the same manner i have written at the bottom.

```
words = "i", "am", "a", "programmer"
list = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
vowels2 = 0 
consonants = 0

for l in words:
    if l in list:
        vowels2 +=1
    else: 
        consonants +=1
    if vowels2 > consonants:
         print(l + "has more vowels than constants")
    else:
        print(l + " has more constanats than vowels")
```

so this is what my expected input will be and the expected output should be
i has more vowels than constants
am has more vowels than constants
a has more vowels than constants
programmer has more constanats than vowels

turns out that all i had to do was remove the second for statement and it works.

Comment: You should also provide the logic, an example input and the expected output ;)

Comment: sorry this is my first time asking and im still very new to codeing so im still getting the hang of it.

Comment: a few comments on your updated code: Do not use `list` as variable name (this is a python builtin), and rather use a set (indexing is faster). Regarding the flow, you do not need a loop once you have the vowel/consonants counts, simply print the result

Comment: i see what you mean but i need the program to output 

i has more vowels than cons

am has more vowels than cons 

etc

Comment: @Morddekaiser have you checked [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71110320/16343464)? Does it do what you want?

Comment: @mozway
your answer works however i have been trying to make it loop so i get four sentances which read. i has more vowels than cons am has more vowels than cons etc

Comment: then simply wrap the whole thing in a loop. Or a function and loop to repeat the function ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to find the longest word in a sentence and determine if it has more vowels or consonants?

A pythonic way of achieving this goal might be:

```
# get input
sentence = 'This is an example sentence'  # you can use `input` here
words = sentence.split()

# find longest word
longestword = max(words, key=len)
print(f'The longest word is "{longestword}" with {len(longestword)} letters.')

# count vowels and compare to the total length
# NB. we assume here that there are only letters in the input
vowels = set('aeiou')
n_vowels = sum(1 for char in longestword.lower() if char in vowels)
a,b = (('vowels', 'consonants') if n_vowels/len(longestword)>0.5
        else ('consonants', 'vowels'))
print(f'The word "{longestword}" contains more {a} than {b}.')
```

output:

```
The longest word is "sentence" with 8 letters.
The word "sentence" contains more consonants than vowels.
```